# Accessing a ContentProvider from an Overlay Class

Tags: android, android-maps, android-contentprovider

How do i call a content provider method from within an overlay class ?

I have a onTap method in my overlay class, where i get the latitude and longitude of the location clicked on the map. I need to insert this record to the content provider. But i cannot do a  getContentResolver().insert().

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the context to the Overlay Class, this is the overlay constructor:

```
public MapViewItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context, int type) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     mContext = context;
     mType=type;
}
```

then use `mContext` inside `onTap()` function as follows:

```
mContext.getContentResolver().insert();
```